# insert values of check buttons to database

Tags: android

i have a problem in my application i want to  insert the values of check buttons but it doesn't work, i had the same difficulty in radio button but you have helped me to solve it, i tried to make the same with check buttons but it didn't go as expected the error comes from the method *public void onClick(View view) :*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 
CheckBox ct1,ct2,ct3,ct4;
   public void  ajouter(View v) {
       db.insertcc(x,y,z,a,b,c);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db.open();

    ct1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.rm_41_1_1);
    ct2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.rm_41_1_2);
    ct3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.rm_41_1_3);
}
        public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.rm_41_1_1:
                if (checked)
                      x=10;
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            case R.id.rm_41_1_2:
                if (checked)
                    y=11;
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            case R.id.rm_41_1_3:
                if (checked)
                    z=33;
                break;
        }
            Button bton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ajout_un);
        bton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                ajouter(v);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
          });
```

}

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: there is no error during execution of application but i get only (0,0,0,0) as values ! thanks for responding

Comment: Please post full cat Log errors trace

Comment: well after tests and searching in this forum, i found the solution, the error is that  i didn't add in the xml file the attribut : android :onClick ="onClick". thanks, with this forum i learn a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after this line

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
```

its mean all clickable views inside layout must be `Checkbox` to prevent this error add this code

```
    boolean checked = false;

//Check if View is CheckBox if not will cancel request
    if (view instanceof CheckBox) 
    {
       if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
               checked = true;
       }
    }else
    {
    return;
    }
```